# Change Number of Posts From tumblr.com/js

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I'm using http://(website).tumblr.com/js to populate the blog on my website, but it only returns the ten most recent posts from my tumblr blog. I want to be able to look up older posts such as posts 11 - 20. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can set the number of posts to return using the `num` parameter:

```
http://WEBSITE.tumblr.com/js?num=40
```

However, it isn't clear how much the value can be (for the standard tumblr API, you can't get more than 50 posts at a time).

If you want a greater degree of customizability, you will probably need to actually use the API and display the content yourself.  The method to get posts is here:

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

And you want to change the `limit` and `offset` parameters.

Comment: I think the limit is 50, default 20....

API 1 - http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1#api_read



API 2 - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tumblr-api/RmLUlbULZbI/40Wx-CToQHkJ

Comment: @Carlton Yes, it is now. It was 20 when I posted this in 2011. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Version 2 of the Tumblr API now uses `limit` instead of `num` among other changes http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts